# Django project 'Improperly Configured: Requested settings INSTALLED APPS' Error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I need help to solve this error which raises when I try to run any python script with Django code.

This is the error:

```
****PS C:\Users\pebr6\Desktop\tutorial> & c:/Users/pebr6/Desktop/pythonEnvironments/1.0/Scripts/Activate.ps1
(1.0) PS C:\Users\pebr6\Desktop\tutorial> & c:/Users/pebr6/Desktop/pythonEnvironments/1.0/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/pebr6/Desktop/tutorial/aplicaciones/principal/models.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/pebr6/Desktop/tutorial/aplicaciones/principal/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Person(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\pebr6\Desktop\pythonEnvironments\1.0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 107, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\pebr6\Desktop\pythonEnvironments\1.0\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\pebr6\Desktop\pythonEnvironments\1.0\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\pebr6\Desktop\pythonEnvironments\1.0\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\pebr6\Desktop\pythonEnvironments\1.0\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before acces**sing settings.******
```

My project structure is the following:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsSds.png%5C)

This is my apps configuration on settings.py:

## Application definition

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'aplicaciones.principal',
]
```

The manage.py file has the next code inside:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tutorial.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the last one, my wsgi.py file:

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tutorial.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()


sys.path.append('C:/Users/pebr6/Desktop/pythonEnvironments/1.0/Scripts/python.exe')
```

My python version is 3.8.3 for 64 bits windows and I'm using virtualenv to create different python environments.

The global environments is on:

**C:\Users\pebr6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe**

I just have virtualenv installed here.

And the virtual environment for my project is on the path:

**c:\Users\pebr6\Desktop\pythonEnvironments\1.0\Scripts\python.exe**

I have django and django rest framework installed here.

The steps that I do to start a project (as an example) are:

1. Create a folder (tutorial as instance).
2. Inside tutorial folder I create another folder called env, where I create a virtual environment using **virtualenv 1.0** on the cmd of windows.
3. Once it's created, I change to that environment and install django and django rest framework using the following commands:

   **pip install django**

   **pip install djangorestframework**

   or

   **python -m pip install django**

   **python -m pip install djangorestframework**
4. Then, inside tutorial folder too, I create a project using:

   **django-admin startproject tutorial .**
5. After this, I create an app with command:

   **manage.py startapp main**

I also tried:

**django-admin startapp main**

or

**python manage.py startapp main**

6. When I open the tutorial folder (which contains env, project and app folders) on VS Code, the IDE ask me for set an interpreter so I search on my computer to find the python.exe on my virtual environment path:

**c:\Users\pebr6\Desktop\pythonEnvironments\1.0\Scripts\python.exe**

So the settings.json changes to this:

**"python.pythonPath": "c:\Users\pebr6\Desktop\pythonEnvironments\1.0\Scripts\python.exe"**

7. Finally I try to write some code on models.py or test.py, or create a serializers.py and start coding. When I run any script, it raise the exception.

The error started happening after I uninstall a python 3.8.3 version for 32 bits by a 64 bits version.
I have tried uninstall all again, I have used both versions with global or virtual environments using virtualenv and the error stills going.

I don't know if this matters but this is what I have on my virtual environment path (that I guess is my PYTHONPATH, not really sure):

[PYTHONPATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKcM8.png)

I tried to open the manage.py shell and run the commands:

**import sys**

**sys.path.append("c:\Users\pebr6\Desktop") or sys.path.append("c:\Users\pebr6\Desktop\tutorial")**

but nothing changes.

I hope someone could help me with this problem that I'm new on python and I don't understand lot of things yet. Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to execute your `models.py` script?

Comment: You should do your testing on `tests.py` and run it using `python manage.py test`, you shouldn't run your `models.py` or any other script.

Comment: yes, I follow the steps on this link  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Comment: See my answer below, it will point you to what you need to follow.

Comment: First I create a class who extends from models.Model and then create the serializer. Once I do that, I import both to my test.py and there, I create an object from **MyClass(models.Model)** and create the serialiazer too as **MyClassSerializer(MyClass)**. And finally, try to see the data to generate the json and look if everything its okay. But the exception keeps going since line **class MyClass(models.Model):** on my models.py

Comment: You don't need this `sys.path.append('C:/Users/pebr6/Desktop/pythonEnvironments/1.0/Scripts/python.exe')`, you've already activated your virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I could solve the problem and it was cause I was writing wrong code.

I was little confused due to before get this error I had run some code which went fine.
When I change the python version (uninstall everything and so on), I had to start a new Django project and well, the problem came when I start to use **models.Model** as a superclass from one of my own classes, which I didn't do last time.

The thing that I wanted to do again is on the next link:

**https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/**

1. Create a simple class (Person for instance) on lets say, models.py
2. Then create a serializer for this object.
3. And finally on another file, import both them and make a test on test.py just creating an instance of my Person class, create the serializer with this instance and for last, generate the json to print.

But the exception came when I tried to extend my Person class to models.Model instead of object, due to I was reading what says in this link:

**https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/**

Both tutorial are right but I was kind of combining code from each other and got that error.

Such error from a python beginner, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run your project scripts like `python models.py`, to use django you must issue `python manage.py` first.

If you want to test your code you should write a test on `tests.py`. [Django's introductory tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial05/) is a good place to start learning how to test on Django. There is also a [topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/) just for testing.